# PHP/SQL - Ignore HTML tags when searching the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a case here where I need to search by course summary which contains data with HTML tags.

Now the case here is I am writing SQL to search by summary. Summary column must contains HTML tags. how can I write the HTML ignoring the HTML tags.

Query to search:

```
$getids = $DB->get_records_sql("SELECT id FROM {course} WHERE (summary LIKE '%$searchcourse%' ) "
```

Way summary  column in db:
[image]

I followed a similar link but couldn't get much information.

Thank You

Comment: You could add another column called something like: `summary_search` where you save the summary without the HTML and search on that column instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not tried it myself.
source: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,177343,177985#msg-177985

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators=1;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fnStripTags;
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION fnStripTags( Dirty varchar(4000) )
RETURNS varchar(4000)
DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
  DECLARE iStart, iEnd, iLength int;
    WHILE Locate( '<', Dirty ) > 0 And Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate( '<', Dirty )) > 0 DO
      BEGIN
        SET iStart = Locate( '<', Dirty ), iEnd = Locate( '>', Dirty, Locate('<', Dirty ));
        SET iLength = ( iEnd - iStart) + 1;
        IF iLength > 0 THEN
          BEGIN
            SET Dirty = Insert( Dirty, iStart, iLength, '');
          END;
        END IF;
      END;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN Dirty;
END;
```

In your code

```
$getids = $DB->get_records_sql("SELECT id FROM {course} WHERE fnStripTags(summary) LIKE '%$searchcourse%'
```

Comment: This function works fine in phpMyAdmin execution, but throws error when the same query runs from the PHP Script

Comment: You will need SUPER privilege to run the first query.